Error Search Form (Variable "form" does not exist.) symfony
I would like to create a search form with symfony
I started by creating a form (Form/SearchType.php)
then render it in the Controller (SearchController.php)
then send the render to the viewer to display the form
(partials/Header.html.twig)
but I get this error: Variable “form” does not exist.
thanks in advance
Header.html.twig:
<header class="hero-header">
    <h1 class="hero-title">
        Désigner.<br>Coder.<br>Assembler.
    </h1>
    <p class="hero-subtitle">
        DevPlanTech : Où Passion et Technologie Se Rencontrent - Explorez les Dernières Tendances, Trouvez les Meilleurs Bons Plans, et Maîtrisez l'Art du Dev et du Design
    </p>
    <div class="search-box">
        {{ form_start(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        {{ form_end(form) }}
    </div>
</header>

Form/SearchType.php:
<?php
namespace App\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SearchType as FormSearchType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class SearchType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
{
        $builder->add('q', FormSearchType::class, [
            'label' => false,
            'attr' => [
            'placeholder' => 'Recherchez un article',
            'aria-label' => 'Recherchez un article'
            ]
        ]);
    }
}

SearchController.php:
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Form\SearchType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Attribute\Route;
use App\Repository\ArticlesRepository;

class SearchController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/search', name: 'search')]
    public function search(Request $request, ArticlesRepository $articlesRepository): Response
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(SearchType::class);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $searchText = $form->get('q')->getData();
            $articles = $articlesRepository->findByKeywordInTitle($searchText);
            return $this->render('partials/search_results.html.twig', [
                'searchText' => $searchText,
                'articles' => $articles,
            ]);
        }

        return $this->render('partials/Header.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
}

